# FreeBSD with Vagrant - don't know how to check guest additions version

Tags: virtualbox, freebsd, vagrant

On Mac OS X 10.9.3

Picked a box from the [VagrantCloud](https://vagrantcloud.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=freebsd)

### Init the vagrant box

```
$ vagrant init chef/freebsd-9.2-i386

A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
```

### List the files

```
$ ls -al
-rw-r--r--  1 joel  staff  4831 Jun  5 17:17 Vagrantfile
```

### Vagrantfile content

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "chef/freebsd-9.2-i386"
end
```

### Starting my virtual box leads to Errors

```
$ vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'chef/freebsd-9.2-i386' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'chef/freebsd-9.2-i386'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/chef/freebsd-9.2-i386
==> default: Adding box 'chef/freebsd-9.2-i386' (v1.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/chef/freebsd-9.2-i386/version/1/provider/virtualbox.box
==> default: Successfully added box 'chef/freebsd-9.2-i386' (v1.0.0) for 'virtualbox'!
==> default: Importing base box 'chef/freebsd-9.2-i386'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'chef/freebsd-9.2-i386' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: freebsd92-i386_default_1401982167145_49633
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2201.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2201 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2201
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
Sorry, don't know how to check guest version of Virtualbox Guest Additions on this platform. Stopping installation.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.16
    default: VirtualBox Version: 4.3
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/joel/Code/anybots/operations/robot/freebsd92-i386
Vagrant attempted to execute the capability 'mount_virtualbox_shared_folder'
on the detect guest OS 'freebsd', but the guest doesn't
support that capability. This capability is required for your
configuration of Vagrant. Please either reconfigure Vagrant to
avoid this capability or fix the issue by creating the capability.
```

Note that I have recently installed the latest version of VirtualBox, but somehow I can't find the Guest Additions.

Answer (score 4):

That error appears because Vagrant tries to use VirtualBox shared folders, however FreeBSD does not support that. Instead, configure Vagrant to use NFS:

```ruby
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "chef/freebsd-10.0"
    config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
end
```

Comment: Does not "just work" (the difference, however, is that I do not use Chef). `vagrant up` just hangs on NFS mounting.